# Do sessions still work for onion websites?

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing, server-administration

Given that many users will come out of the same exit node for any given site, do sessions still for for onion websites?

ie. Will the people that come out of the same exit node be all logged in as the same user when they visit the site?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, sessions still work, and no, users won't be logged in all the same. Website sessions are stored client-side, so every client will have a unique session.